# Passing table for JOIN using CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql, left-join, inner-join

I'm trying to use a CASE WHEN statement to determine which table to use for the latter half of a JOIN. For example, there are 3 tables: TableA, TableB, TableC.

```
SELECT a.column1, b.column2
FROM
TableA as a
FULL OUTER JOIN
CASE WHEN condition1 THEN TableB as b
ELSE TableC as b
END
ON a.ID = b.ID

Example:

TableA
ID: 1 2 3
Column1: 10 20 30

TableB
ID: 1 2 3
Column2: 100 200 300

TableC
ID: 1 2 3
Column2: 1000 2000 3000

-- Result 1 --> CASE WHEN statement is true, TableA and TableB are joined

Column1: 10 20 30
Column2: 100 200 300

-- Result 2 --> CASE WHEN statement is false, TableA and TableC are joined

Column1: 10 20 30
Column2: 1000 2000 3000
```

I always want to use TableA for the join, but then depending on a certain condition, I want to join either TableB or TableC. Regardless of which second table is used for the join, I want it to be referenced as "b" so that the ON condition can just use b.ID and the SELECT statement will always use b.column2

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  A SQL query begins with `SELECT`, not `TableA`, so your code is not a valid query.

Comment: (1) You can't have two tables with the same alias in the same `from` clause, so the last part of your question is just not possible (2) Please provide sample data and desired results; what you ask for is still probably doable, although not in the way you imagine it is.

Comment: Added an example!

Answer (score 0):

You can `left join` twice. The condition goes to the `on` clause of the each join:

```
select a.col1, coalesce(b.col2, c.col2) as col2
from tablea a
left join tableb b 
    on  b.id = a.id
    and (condition)      -- condition is met
left join tablec c 
    on  c.id = a.id   
    and not (condition)  -- condition is not met
```

Comment: The file I'm working with is very large and takes quite a bit of time to produce TableA, TableB and TableC, so I was hoping to avoid querying for TableB or TableC if they weren't needed. If I'm following correctly, the above code would ALWAYS query for TableB and TableC regardless of if they're used, right? Wondering if there's a way to only query for the 2 tables I need.

Comment: @Matt: the database will make the decision on which table should be queried or not. Don't optimize prematurely. Adapt the query for your actual use case, then test it, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can union the two tables including the condition, so as to get the rows of one or the other:

```
SELECT a.column1, b.column2
FROM TableA a
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT id, column2 FROM TableB WHERE <condition>
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, column2 FROM TableC WHERE NOT <condition>
) b ON a.id = b.id
```